Compatibility Issue with Keyboards in Setting Stickers/GIFs on ImageView
I attempted to set stickers/gifs on ImageView, but encountered compatibility issues with certain keyboards. Keyboards such as Kika Keyboard, Emoji Keyboard, Emoji & Font Keyboard, and Facemoji Keyboard Lite are not functioning properly. The error message displayed is: "This textbox can't support gif/sticker."
However, keyboards such as gboard, Google AI Keyboard, and bitmoji Keyboard are functioning correctly.
Please assist me in identifying any errors in my code.
MainActivity -
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ImageView stickerImageView;
    
     MyEditText myEditText;

    EditText et_text;

    Context mContext;
    
    
     @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mContext=getApplicationContext();

        et_text = findViewById(R.id.et_text);
        stickerImageView = findViewById(R.id.stickerImageView);


         myEditText = findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
         
         
         
          myEditText.setKeyBoardInputCallbackListener(new MyEditText.KeyBoardInputCallbackListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCommitContent(InputContentInfoCompat inputContentInfo,
                                        int flags, Bundle opts) {
                ClipDescription clipDescription = inputContentInfo.getDescription();
                String mimeType = clipDescription.getMimeType(0);

                Log.d("MyEditText", "mimeType: mimeType - " + mimeType);

                //you will get your gif/png/jpg here in inputContentInfo
                // You can use a webView or ImageView to load the gif

//                Uri linkUri = inputContentInfo.getLinkUri();
//
//                Log.d("MyEditText", "onCommitContent: linkUri - " + linkUri);

                Log.d("MyEditText", "onCommitContent: Description - " + inputContentInfo.getDescription());
                Log.d("MyEditText", "onCommitContent: LinkUri - " + inputContentInfo.getLinkUri());


                // Retrieve the image/gif data from inputContentInfo
                Uri contentUri = inputContentInfo.getContentUri();

                Log.d("MyEditText", "onCommitContent: contentUri - " + contentUri);
                try {
                    // Check if the content is a GIF
                    if (inputContentInfo.getDescription().hasMimeType("image/gif")) {
                        InputStream inputStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(contentUri);
                        byte[] gifBytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
                        inputStream.read(gifBytes);
                        // Load the GIF bytes into an ImageView
                        Glide.with(mContext).asGif().load(gifBytes).into(stickerImageView);
                    } else {
                        // Load the PNG into an ImageView
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(contentUri));
                        stickerImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.e("MyEditText", "Failed to load image/gif", e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("MyEditText", "IOException", e);
                }

            }
        });

    }
}

MyEditText -
public class MyEditText extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText {

    private String[] imgTypeString;
    private KeyBoardInputCallbackListener keyBoardInputCallbackListener;

    public MyEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView();
        Log.d("MyEditText", "Context - " + context);
    }

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView();

        Log.d("MyEditText", "AttributeSet - " + attrs);
    }

    private void initView() {
        imgTypeString = new String[]{
                "image/*",
                "image/png",
                "image/apng",
                "image/avif",
                "image/gif",
                "image/jpg",
                "image/jpe",
                "image/jpeg",
                "image/jfif",
                "image/jif",
                "image/pjpeg",
                "image/pjp",
                "image/webp",
                "image/svg",
                "image/bmp",
                "image/ico",
                "image/cur",
                "image/svg+xml",
                "image/x-icon",
                "image/tif",
                "image/tiff",
                "image/x-xcf",
                "image/x-ms-bmp",
                "image/vnd.wap.wbmp",
                "image/xbm",
                "image/xbitmap",
        };
    }





    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        final InputConnection ic = super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);
        EditorInfoCompat.setContentMimeTypes(outAttrs,
                imgTypeString);
        return InputConnectionCompat.createWrapper(ic, outAttrs, callback);
    }




    final InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener callback =
            new InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onCommitContent(InputContentInfoCompat inputContentInfo,
                                               int flags, Bundle opts) {


                    if (inputContentInfo == null) {
                        Log.d("MyEditText", "inputContentInfo is null");
                        return false;
                    }

                    // read and display inputContentInfo asynchronously
                    if (BuildCompat.isAtLeastNMR1() && (flags &
                            InputConnectionCompat.INPUT_CONTENT_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) != 0) {
                        try {
                            inputContentInfo.requestPermission();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            return false; // return false if failed
                        }
                    }
                    boolean supported = false;
                    for (final String mimeType : imgTypeString) {
//                        Log.d("MyEditText", "mimeType - " + mimeType);
                        if (inputContentInfo.getDescription().hasMimeType(mimeType)) {
                            supported = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!supported) {
                        Log.d("MyEditText", "Unsupported content type");

                        return false;
                    }

                    if (keyBoardInputCallbackListener != null) {
                        Log.d("MyEditText", "keyBoardInputCallbackListener - " + keyBoardInputCallbackListener);
                        keyBoardInputCallbackListener.onCommitContent(inputContentInfo, flags, opts);
                    }else {
                        Log.d("MyEditText", "keyBoardInputCallbackListener - " + keyBoardInputCallbackListener);

                    }
                    return true;  // return true if succeeded
                }
            };

    public interface KeyBoardInputCallbackListener {
        void onCommitContent(InputContentInfoCompat inputContentInfo,
                             int flags, Bundle opts);
    }

    public void setKeyBoardInputCallbackListener(KeyBoardInputCallbackListener keyBoardInputCallbackListener) {

        Log.d("MyEditText", "keyBoardInputCallbackListener - " + keyBoardInputCallbackListener);
        this.keyBoardInputCallbackListener = keyBoardInputCallbackListener;
    }

    public String[] getImgTypeString() {
        return imgTypeString;
    }

    public void setImgTypeString(String[] imgTypeString) {
        this.imgTypeString = imgTypeString;
    }
}

Manifests -
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

1)gboard

2)Emoji keyboard

